# Is the phrase "alone work" legitimate?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, phrases, word-order

For the purpose of a cover letter, would it be legitimate to use the phrase "alone work" to describe your past professional activities that were conducted individually? Is it grammatically correct? And also, is it a phrase that would be used by English speakers?

As far as I have googled, I have not found many phrases online that use this phrase, but there are a few. And let's assume that I cannot use "working alone" instead, because I have a lot of phrases starting like this (doing this, doing that etc). I am interested in the correctness of mentioned phrase.

Comment: I'd use *solo work* for that activity.

Comment: No, it isn't - _alone_ as adjective isn't used before a noun (though _lone_ can be).

Comment: Ever hear the trick interview question about preferring solo work or teamwork? All work has some of each, but management wants to hear you can work on teams. Emphasizing solo work can be a mistake as much as beginning two sentences in a row with "I."

Comment: @KateBunting  [Alone time](https://www.verywellmind.com/how-important-is-alone-time-for-mental-health-5184607) (= time alone) may be one exception.

Comment: @KateBunting would you know why lone can be used like this and alone not? How can I differentiate them since they are both adjectives?

Comment: No, I don't know - it's just 'the way English works', and something you have to learn.

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly by "conducted individually".  Were you a freelancer who found your own projects? Or were you working for a small company where you weren't part of a team?

Comment: @TimR hm, to give some context, I am an aspiring software developer and I was trying to refer to projects that I have completed alone (as a student) and not as part of a team.

Comment: Were these projects part of your education --projects for classes-- or were they as an intern at  a company?

Comment: @TimR part of my education, but I don't have anything else to showcase.

Comment: @TimR but I have done an internship and worked alone on something, so I guess maybe that counts?

Comment: Yes, an internship counts.

Answer (score 1):

When "alone" is used as an adjective, it is used as a ***predicative adjective***, meaning that it is an adjective that usually comes after a linking verb and **not** before a noun.

Quoting [an article called "Alone, lonely, or lonesome?" on the Cambridge Dictionary website](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/alone-lonely-or-lonesome):

> Alone is an adjective and an adverb meaning that no other person is
> with you. When we use alone as an adjective, **it never comes before the
> noun (predicative adjective)**:
>
> ```
> She was alone when she heard the sad news. (adjective)
>
> It’s impossible to discuss as a committee. The chairman alone will decide. (adverb)
>
> Did they travel alone or did they take the children with them? (adverb)
>
> Do you live alone? (adverb)
> ```